# What happens to debt to SSA after death?

Tags: united-states, non-resident, debt, social-security, mexico

A woman in another country was married to her late husband. She notified about his death right away but SSA kept sending money from his Social Security benefits. She thought that everything was in order since she notified without delays and that it was ok to make use of the money. 3 years later was asked by SSA to return it.

She is trying to pay back little by little as she doesn't have too much income but she fears she may die before being able to pay back and leave the debt to her loved ones.

She is not a US citizen. Her husband was.